# Простой редактор изображений JS

Tags: javascript, изображения, редактор

Товарищи, возникла следующая проблема: сейчас работаю над одним сайтом, где появилась необходимость в простеньком редакторе изображений на стороне клиента. 
Из необходимых возможностей там:

- `Выделение` прямоугольной области
- Добавление `текста` и его дальнейшее перемещение по области изображения
- Возможность `откатить` сделанное

Как то обычно бывает, под каждую задачу для `JS` уже написан framework, однако никаких полезных библиотек, которые бы соответствовали описанным задачам, я не нашёл. Пытаюсь сейчас реализовать сам, однако наткнулся на множество подводных камней и опасаюсь, что реализация в итоге выйдет кривой и нескоро ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Если у Вас есть на примете какие-либо библиотеки или идеи по реализации, буду очень признателен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть неплохой редактор на JS: [TUI Image Editor](http://nhnent.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/tutorial-example01-basic.html).
Неплохая документация, если в JS хоть немного есть опыта, то с легкостью можно интегрировать и оформить на свой вкус.

Answer (score 3):

Есть не плохой [miniPaint](https://github.com/viliusle/miniPaint). Его легко интегировать и можо выгружать картинки в разном формате.

Comment: Согласен, редактор хороший, однако, к сожалению, больше под логику моего сайта подходит более легковесный вариант, предложенный в другом ответе. Спасибо за совет, плюс ставлю, однако галочку, увы, отдаю другому ответу ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯